# an error response 215 in twitter API in C#

Tags: c#, twitter

I am trying to call following Twitter's API to get a list of tweets for specific hashtag.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40rose

Allways  this error response appears.

> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

is there any suggestions ?

Comment: Is your authentication data bad? That seems to be the gist of the error.

Comment: how can i check wither the  authentication data bad or not?

Answer (score 1):

Googling Twitter's API response codes quickly returns the following information:

> Typically sent with 1.1 responses with HTTP code 400. The method
>   requires authentication but it was not presented or was wholly
>   invalid.

I would advise you to check your authentication.

Source: [Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)